# Keep everything centered for different browser resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I am trying to keep everything centered as the browser changes size. I have tried messing around with the position, but I haven't gotten that to work for everything.

I'm also having trouble centering my font-awesome icons. They are too far to the right, which I have tried to counter by setting it to `left: 49%;` but that just makes it even more wonky as the sizes shift around.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #21d4fd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(19deg, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
  background-size: 10%, 10%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  animation: change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#name {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-kerning: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

#schoolText {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.mainText {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  line-height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
  left: 1%;
  top: 95%;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background-position: 0, 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100%, 50%;
  }
  10% {
    background-position: 0, 50%;
  }
}

.media {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  transform: translateY(-53%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.btn i {
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 35px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn :hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainText">
  <h1 id="name">Nick</h1>
  <p id="schoolText">Professional Harvard Dropout</p>
</div>
<h6>Centered</h6>
<!-- Social Media Icons -->
<div class="media" style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="btn" href="#">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">
    <i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try flex?

Comment: often an easy way to center something horizontally (block level elements) is to set a width and margin:auto.

Comment: all possible ways of centering in CSS are [shown here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)